# Finding Infimum of set

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Say we have a set $F=\left\{4+\frac{2}{n^3}:n\in\mathbb{N}\right\}$

We assume $F$ is bounded below by $4$, since

$4\lt4+\frac{2}{n^3}$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$

We now show $m=4$ is the greatest lower bound of $F$ by proving that if $m'\gt4$ there is an element $4+\frac{2}{n^3}$ in $F$ such that $4+\frac{2}{n^3}\lt m'$. If $m'\gt4$

$$
\begin{align}
4+\frac{2}{n^3}\lt m'&\Leftrightarrow \frac{2}{n^3}\lt m'-4\\
&\Leftrightarrow\frac{n^3}{2} \gt \frac{1}{m'-4}\\
&\Leftrightarrow n^3 \gt \frac{2}{m'-4}\\
&\Leftrightarrow n \gt \sqrt[3]{\frac{2}{m'-4}}
\end{align}
$$

If we take a positive integer $n$ that $n\gt \sqrt[3]{\frac{2}{m'-4}}$, this gives a number $4+\frac{2}{n^3}$ in $F$ such that $4+\frac{2}{n^3} \lt m'$.

Therefore $4$ is the greatest lowest bound of $F$

Am I right in my conclusion?

Comment: The reciprocal of $m'-4$ isn't $\frac{1}{m'}-\frac{1}{4}$

Comment: What should it be?

Comment: Only $\frac{1}{m'-4}$, these are two different things $\frac{1}{m'}-\frac{1}{4}\ne\frac{1}{m'-4}$

Comment: Good call, I've modified original question to suit. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $m'>4$, since $\frac{2}{n^3}\rightarrow 0$, there exists $N$ such that $\forall n\geq N$,
$$ 0< \frac{2}{n^3} \leq \frac{m'-4}{2}$$

In particular $m'>4+\frac{2}{N^3}\in F$, so we can't have $m'>4$ and $4$ is the greatest lower bound of $F$.

No calculus is needed...

But if you really want to :
$$
\begin{align}
4+\frac{2}{n^3}\lt m'&\Leftrightarrow \frac{2}{n^3}\lt m'-4\\
&\Leftrightarrow  \frac{2}{m'-4}\lt n^3 \\
&\Leftrightarrow n \gt \sqrt[3]{\frac{2}{m'-4}} 
\end{align}
$$

Comment: No calculus is used. We take $m'$ as a variable in relation $m$. This notation based on the real analysis material I have been reading

Comment: @whitelined: so, I answered your question, right?